# Yii2 Basic insert to table after click on link

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm trying to create a link in view to insert data on table using view and controller

on view my code

```
<?= Html::a('Insert', ['view'], ['value' => 'insertdata' 'class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
```

but I dont know how to refresh page and insert data to table

my data is

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $InsertChannel = new Channelmembers();

    if (Yii::$app->request->post('submit') == 'insertdata') {
        $InsertChannel->User_id = Yii::$app->user->getId();;
        $InsertChannel->Channel_id = $id;
        $InsertChannel->insert();
    }

    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: maybe you need method post `<?= Html::a('Insert', ['view'], ['value' => 'insertdata' 'class' => 'btn btn-primary' 'data' => [
                'confirm' => "?",
                'method' => 'post',
            ]]) ?>`

Comment: I get this error syntax error, unexpected ''class'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ']'

Comment: Replace 'btn btn-primary' 'data' for 'btn btn-primary','data' or check the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<?= Html::a('Insert', ['view', 'id' => $model->id], [
    'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
    'data'  => [
        'method' => 'POST',
        'params' => [
            'submit' => 'insertdata',
        ],
    ],
]) ?>
```

*Note: I added the extra `'id' => $model->id` parameter which you will need to pass according to your view action.*

Comment: it's not access the if condition on my controller

Comment: my view is <?= Html::a('Insert', ['view', 'id' => $model->id], [
   'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
   'data'  => [
    'method' => 'POST',
    'params' => [
     'value' => 'insertdata',
    ],
   ],
  ])?>

Comment: public function actionView($id)
    {
  $ly_JoingChannel = new Channelmembers();
  if (Yii::$app->request->post('submit') == 'insertdata') {
   var_dump ('hello'); die;
  }
  
  return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        ]);
    }

Comment: try a var_dump on Yii::$app->request->post() and post it to your answer

Comment: @Bynd you are still passing 'value' instead of 'submit'.

Comment: It dosn't do nothing with var_dump

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you are checking the 
`if (Yii::$app->request->post('submit') == 'insertdata') {`

for the post where as if you will try too set the `data-param` name `submit` inside the anchor's `data` attribute manually it will not allow you to click the link instead it will do nothing, you have to change the name of the variable you are checking in the action to `Submit` or any other because there is a know [**`BUG`**](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/15791) in `yii.js` to be fixed in **`V 2.0.15`**

`if (Yii::$app->request->post('Submit') == 'insertdata') {`

then you can make the link like below

```
<?=Html::a('Insert', ['view', 'id' => $model->id], [
    'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
    'data' => [
        'method' => 'POST',
        'params' => ['Submit' => 'insertdata'],
    ],
]
)?>
```